# Remove first comma in a string with Python

Tags: python, string

I have this string

```
s = "1,395,54"
```

I would like to remove the first comma to obtain the following string:

```
s = "1395,54"
```

What is the most efficient way to solve this simple problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), it takes a third argument which specifies the number of occurrences to replace.

```
>>> your_str = "1,395,54"
>>> your_str.replace(",", "", 1)
'1395,54'
```

Answer (score 0):

By slicing the string. The `find` method return the index of the first match

```
s = "1,395,54"

index = s.find(',')
print(s[:index] + s[index+1:])
```